# unwanted text as part of font change

Tags: fonts

I have the following line:

```
{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{Latin Modern}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont P} is the total 2010 population in urban areas in Maricopa County or in sensitivity groups.
```

The output shows:

> modern.fd Modern.fd P is the total 2010 population in urban areas for
>   Maricopa County or in sensitivity groups.

I am not sure why the text "modern.fd Modern.fd" is appearing. Oddly, it only appears in the first instance of that line of code; i.e., I have repeated the line in different parts of the same `.tex` file, and in subsequent instances, it displays the "P" character in Latin Modern, as I intended.

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for `\fontfamily{lmr}`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{lmr}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont P} is the total 2010 population in urban areas in Maricopa County or in sensitivity groups.

\end{document}
```

The above can be simplified using `\usefont`:

```
{\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}P} is the total 2010 population in urban areas in Maricopa County or in sensitivity groups.
```

And, of course, if this is going to be used many times, you can define a command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myP{{\usefont{T1}{lmr}{m}{n}P}}

\begin{document}

\myP{} is the total 2010 population in urban areas in Maricopa County or in sensitivity groups.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Ramakan you're welcome! Don't forget that you can up-vote good answers and accept the one you consider solved your problem, by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).